# VSCode Junit output not displaying

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and just installed VSCode 1.35.1. I installed the Java packages, created a project from maven, and then tried to run the unit tests. The tests run, but none of the print messages are showing anywhere.

My launch.json looks like this,

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch)-App<ttt>",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "exercises.App",
            "projectName": "ttt",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run with F5 or Ctrl-F5, it always runs the main App. When I go to my test file and click on the Run|Debug links, the tests run and generate reports, but I don't see any of the print messages I put in.

What do I need to setup differently?

Answer (score 1):

The Test Output is in the Java Test Runner Output. 
You can highlight it with the "Java: Show Test Output" command in the F1 menu

Answer (score 1):

With VSCode 1.64 (Jan. 2022), you won't have to look for that view anymore when launching a debug session.
It allows for VS Code to automatically switch to test explorer when users click '`run tests`'.

See [issue 140596](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140596) / [issue 135999](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135999), solved by [commit a47b55c](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/a47b55caafe8c6c011fb2a426d89007c3027fae9)

You now have the options:

- `NeverOpen` = '`neverOpen`',
- `OpenOnTestStart` = '`openOnTestStart`',
- `OpenOnTestFailure` = '`openOnTestFailure`',